# Baseline not working as expected in react-native

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

Today i  tried to use following property - `alignItems: 'baseline'`
Whole code:

```
<View
  style={{
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    alignItems: "baseline",
    top: "6%",
    left: 12,
    flex: 1,
  }}
>
  <Text style={{ color: "#c1c3c9", fontSize: 24 }}>question</Text>
  <Text style={{ color: "#c1c3c9", fontSize: 26 }}>2</Text>
  <Text style={{ color: "#51546e", fontSize: 24 }}>/16</Text>
</View>
```

and image from emulator

[image]

I want to put this on whole line.
Where is the problem?

Comment: Can you explained what you expect? Because in your screenshot text aligned by baseline